# Delete confirmation returns Undefined in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am facing this issue in Chrome only.

When I want to delete an entity in my web application before that I ask for confirmation for delete.

```
<div onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete package?');">
  <a href="appsubscriptionpackagedelete.htm?appguid=${appGuid}&packageguid=${packageGuid}" onclick="return confirm()" class="iconbutton trashicon FloatRight"></a>
</div>
```

When I click delete link it gives proper message in other browsers but returns undefined in Chrome. If I click cancel then it shows proper alert with string passed in confirm function

Comment: @mplungjan <div onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete package?');">
      <a href="appsubscriptionpackagedelete.htm?appguid=${appGuid}&packageguid=${packageGuid}" onclick="return confirm()" class="iconbutton trashicon FloatRight"></a>
      </div>

Comment: The answer is to have the onclick on the link, not the div

Comment: @mplungjan I have edited question you can refer it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return false only works on the link

```
<div >
  <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete package?');"
href="appsubscriptionpackagedelete.htm?appguid=${appGuid}&packageguid=${packageGuid}"  class="iconbutton trashicon FloatRight"></a>
</div>
```